# How do I get true caller access rights for a directory in afs?

Tags: openafs

According to the openAFS docs,  `fs getcalleracces some_path` should give me my effective rights to "some_path".

When I run this command on some directories I get

```
Callers access to . is rlidwk
```

While this does not include the 'a' administer rights, in actuality, I can change the permissions to this directory (probably because I am the owner of the volume).  For example `fs sa some_path some_id rw`  works fine.

Is there some way I can check that I am the owner of the volume?  I can't seem to find any commands in the openAFS docs that provide this info.

Answer (score 1):

The owner of the root directory of a volume has implied administrator rights within the volume.  Based on reading the doc for "fs getcalleraccess", I would think it should pick this up and report it.  If it's not doing so, that seems like a bug to me.

I guess as a workaround, you could walk back through the directory hierarchy from the path you're interested in, working backwards towards "/", until you find a mount point, and then check who the owner of the root directory of the volume is, and assume that user has implied administrator rights and react according (regardless of what "fs getcalleraccess" is telling you).  Though that's kind of a gross hack.

There's no command (that I'm aware of) that will tell you who the owner of the volume is - you have to actually mount the volume and look at who the owner of the root directory of the volume is.

Comment: Thanks, Pat.  I agree it does seem like a bug.  My goal was to actually check that a user had permission to changes an acl, before attempting to change it.  I could probably fall back to making a test run, for example trying to apply a permission I already have and look for an error, but that seems kind of hacky too.  I will leave this open for a day so, If I don't get any better answer I will check it off and maybe file a bug report on openafs